# Conditional echo based on results of grep

Tags: shell, grep, rhel

I have the following command that will output how many connections I have on a given port:

```
while true
do
    echo -n "number of connections: "
    netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -w <Port Number> | wc -l
    date
    printf '\n'
    sleep 0.3
done | grep -v "number of connections: 0"
```

if the number of connections is 0, I would not like to print anything. However since the date prints on a separate line the grep does not apply to the date command.

Here is some sample output:

```
Tue Nov 17 16:42:48 EST 2020

Tue Nov 17 16:42:49 EST 2020

number of connections: 1
Tue Nov 17 16:42:49 EST 2020

number of connections: 3
Tue Nov 17 16:42:49 EST 2020

number of connections: 2
Tue Nov 17 16:42:50 EST 2020
```

the first two lines are what is printed when the number of connections is 0, however my desired output (based on the above sample output) would just be:

```
number of connections: 1
Tue Nov 17 16:42:49 EST 2020

number of connections: 3
Tue Nov 17 16:42:49 EST 2020

number of connections: 2
Tue Nov 17 16:42:50 EST 2020
```

Comment: Count the number of connections. If it's non-zero then output your message with the number of connections you've just counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign your count to a variable

```
count=$(netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -w <Port Number> | wc -l)
if [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; then #issue your echo or printf
```